# Unable to access a HKEY_CURRENT_USER subkey with c#

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64

I am trying to access the registry sub key SecureProtocols in the key:
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" to automate a TLS/SSL test.

I am able to access other sub keys in "CurrentVersion" but "Internet Settings" returns null.

Here is the usual way I access keys:

```
        public static string SetIESecureProtocols(string dWordValue = "0")
        {
            using (RegistryKey internetSettingsKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
                "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true))
            {
                if (internetSettingsKey != null)
                {
                    const string key = "SecureProtocols";
                    var keyValue = internetSettingsKey.GetValue(key);
                    if (keyValue != null && keyValue.ToString() != dWordValue)
                    {
                        var secureProtocolsBackup = keyValue.ToString();
                        internetSettingsKey.SetValue(key, dWordValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                        internetSettingsKey.Close();
                        return secureProtocolsBackup;
                    }
                    internetSettingsKey.Close();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I have tried executing this function with a separate elevated exe.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

My domain user has full control and read access to the "Internet Settings" key.

No matter what I do, "internetSettingsKey" variable is null.
The key DOES exist and the value of "SecureProtocols" changes when I manually change the settings in Internet Explorer advanced options.

I am able to manually change the key in the Registry Editor.

I am on a 64 bit system but the "Internet Settings" key does not exist in:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node

Thanks in advance!

Update:
After further investigation I have tried a few other options.

- VBS: I am able to read and change the key with
  this method.
- Batch (reg command): I am able to read and change the key with
  this method.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code line by line to see what it's actually doing and observing the values of your variables at each step?  I suspect your code isn't doing what you think it's doing...

Comment: Try passing in all the rights that you want e.g. `OpenSubKey(keyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl);`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @roryap Yes I have stepped through to check the values.

Comment: @ Conrad Just tried passing in those rights and it was still null. Thanks though.

Comment: @Hans I have tried using RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey and setting the RegistryView.

Comment: Ah, of course, we can tell from your snippet.

Comment: Are you running this from an ordinary interactive session?  (That is, not from a service, from a remote system, etc.)

Comment: Works fine for me.  (I didn't try setting the value, but the other bits of your code are working perfectly.)

Comment: @Harry Sigh, I am running on the local machine under my domain user account so nothing fancy. Thanks for trying the code! It may have something to do with the domains policy. It does not work on a co-workers machine either. I've updated the post with my latest findings.

Comment: Hmmm.  Bit of a long shot, but Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) might give you a clue as to what's going on.  One thought: are you sure the code is running with full trust?  For example, if you run a .NET application from a network share, it doesn't get full trust so there are things it won't be allowed to do.  (Or at least that used to be the case, I haven't been keeping up with all the .NET changes over the past decade or so.)  You can also [explicitly sandbox code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Harry I checked out Process Monitor and the result from the key read was "NAME NOT FOUND". I do not know if it is running trusted or not. The exe file is local and not on a network drive.

Comment: OK, if "name not found" was shown in Process Monitor that's pretty much conclusive - the registry key the code is attempting to access doesn't exist.  What name does Process Monitor show for the access?  (Actually, I guess there is one other possible explanation: anti-virus or other security software.)

Comment: @Harry That's whats so odd about this. The key does exist as proven by being able to get it through vbs and bat using the same path. I don't see anything about access other than "Desired Access: Read/Write". I checked the access log in Mcafee and I do not see the events when I tried getting the key. I do see other events that access various sub keys of Internet Settings, but it also says "rule is currently not enforced" My exe is not found in the access log.

Comment: Try comparing what Process Monitor says when you use your exe compared to what it says when you use the `reg` command.  If you are able to temporarily uninstall (not just disable) McAfee that would be worth trying.  Or if you can set up a test machine or VM you could see if it is something about your domain environment or perhaps some particular piece of third-party software.  Even just confirming that you can make it work would be some information. :-)  Also, have you tried an application that runs *just* that one snippet of code?

Comment: @Harry Yes, the exe I built does only this one function. I can't disable McAfee as it's policy enforced on all machines in it :/ Only difference I see in process monitor is instead of NAME NOT FOUND it says SUCCESS. Few other differences in the stack and modules. Nothing that stood out to me.

Comment: A few more thoughts: perhaps McAfee wouldn't trigger if you digitally signed the application?  Are you able to confirm that your test executable works under ordinary circumstances by, e.g., running it on your personal machine at home?  And I suppose as a workaround you could always shell out to a `reg` command, seeing as that works.

Comment: @Harry Yes, I am going to stick with the VBS solution for now. Thanks for all your help!